# How to unit test not safe integers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, integer, rounding, integer-overflow

Here's Typescript.

I have a function (Angular pipe actually) what converts number of days to string like '1 day' or '2 days' depended on input.

```
transform(day: number): string {
  const result = /* here's a logic */;
  return result; // outputs smthg like '1 day' or '5 days'
}
```

I write unit tests for it and they don't pass when I write superlarge numbers like 12312512135351513.

I have suggestion that it's about safe integer limits and my input overflows it.

So question is: **how to test functions what receive such unsafe integer inputs?**
Their outputs are unexpected.

Avoiding unsafe numbers is a solution, but is it a good one? Another one is get number as a string, cut the last digit and use it, but function's API will look strangely.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without the given data, but your code has a bug if it does not produce what your expect. Code should be predictable and it sounds like you just found an edge case where it either is not or not predictable in the manner you expect. So avoid the unsafe number if you can

Comment: you can check if number is always less than [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) or use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to deal with large numbers.

Comment: @Leon, I like your thought about unexpected behavior = bug, that's enough to decide to avoid unsafe numbers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`const testUpper = (num) => Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER > num`

A basic test in javascript for really long numbers in js. Hope this helps